# Iterate over different length df & export to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, export-to-csv

When my df2, Group2 has the third item 'B3', I get what I want regarding the groupby. How can I get the output when the arrays are different lengths? 
I also struggle with getting all data to CSV, not just the last iteration. I tried making the df before the loop and then merging it within, but something doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'C13'], 
                    'Whole': ['full', 'full', 'full', 'semi', 'semi', 'semi']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 
                    'Group2': ['B1', 'B2']})

for column in df2.columns:
    
    d_group = df1[df1.Title.isin(df2[column])]
        
    df = d_group.groupby('Whole')['Whole'].count()\
                    .rename('Column Name from df2')\
                    .reindex(['part', 'full', 'semi'], fill_value='-')\
                    .reset_index()
    
    df.T.to_csv('all_groups2.csv', header=False, index=True)
    print(df.T)
```

Desired output:

```
    Whole   | part    | full     | semi
    --------+---------+----------+----------
    Group1  | -       | 3        | -
    Group2  | -       | -        | 2
```

Comment: It is not clear what's the expected output. Could you please post your desired output as a table?

Comment: Done, the code works if you add 'B3' to Group2 in df2

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas Dataframe, it is expected to have columns (or rows) with the same shapes. Therefore, it is not possible to have `df2` in your code.

I recommend using the Series instead, something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'C13'], 
                    'Whole': ['full', 'full', 'full', 'semi', 'part', 'semi']})
group1 = pd.Series(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
group2 = pd.Series(['B1', 'B2'])
```

Then, you can filter and groupby dataframe `df1` by `isin` function:

```
dfg1 = df1[df1['Title'].isin(group1)].groupby('Whole').count()
dfg2 = df1[df1['Title'].isin(group2)].groupby('Whole').count()
```

And finally join them by `concat` on `axis=1`:

```
res = pd.concat([dfg1, dfg2], axis=1)
res.columns = ['Group1','Group2']
finaldf = res.T
```

The result is the following:

```
        full  part  semi
Group1   3.0   NaN   NaN
Group2   NaN   1.0   1.0
```

And finally, you can write it to a CSV with the same code that you had:

```
finaldf.to_csv('result.csv', header=False, index=True)
```

I recommend not writing row by row to a file, unless it is a very huge file and you cannot store it in memory. In that case, I recommend partitioning or using Dask.

Comment: I see, this is how I actually started but I have so many groups that it didn't seem like a great option.

Comment: If you have many groups and you want to use dataframe, you can combine the series (e.g. group1, group2) with concat, like ```df2 = pd.concat([group1,group2],axis=1)```. It puts NaN where the shape does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I could just load my df2 as pd.series, and iterate over the index, not column, to get where I wanted to be.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'], 
                    'ID': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'A1', 'D2', 'D3'], 
                    'Whole': ['full', 'full', 'full', 'semi', 'semi', 'semi']})

df2 = pd.Series({'Group1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 
                 'Group2': ['B1', 'B2']})

df = pd.DataFrame()

for index in df2.index:
    
    d_group = (df1[df1.ID.isin(df2[index])])
     
    df3 = d_group.groupby('Whole')['Whole'].count()\
                .rename(index, inplace=True)\
                .reindex(['part', 'full', 'semi'], fill_value='-')
    df = df.append(df3, ignore_index=False, sort=False)
        
print(df)
```